# Call REST repeatedly in Angular (5)

Tags: angular, rest, typescript, rxjs, long-polling

I need create service which will be consume data from long-polling rest service in my backend. When I call this service, backend wait until it has data to send or timeout is expired and send just empty object.

In angular I want service which starts when application is completely loaded, and will be running in background and push data to subjects which I observer.

Can tell me what is the best practice or show me example how to should this service in angular looks like?

Here is my try but it nor call rest on start:

```
@Injectable()
export class PollingService {

  private url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fooService: FooService) {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/poll';
    this.startPolling();
  }

  startPolling() {
    this.http.get<any>(this.url)
      .map(pollData => {
        console.log('poll data', pollData);
        this.fooService.mySubject.next(pollData);
        if (pollData)
          this.startPolling();
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Observable.timer(0, 5000)`. Calls every 5 seconds.

Comment: When you say "timeout is expired and send just empty object" is that just for the first attempt or all attempts?

Comment: Do you really want to start requesting data on app load or would you rather wait till you know that something in your app wants it? If it is subscription based then you wont be hitting the api while no one cares about the data.

Comment: @User3250 I can't use that because I have logic on backend ... request is completed when there are new data on server or time is expired. So request can took any time from 1 to X seconds.

Comment: @bygrace it's for all.

Comment: @bygrace yes I need requesting to server until user close application or logout.

Comment: Is the timeout shorter than or equal to the polling interval?

Comment: @bygrace check my code please. I indicate that I want call service again when I got result from previous request. if (recivedData) { // do someting and call this method again }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not getting any data from the service is because you haven't subscribe to it.

A working example could look like this:

```
startPolling() {
    this.http.get<any>('url').subscribe((pollData) => {
        console.log('poll data', pollData);
        this.fooService.mySubject.next(pollData);
        if (pollData)
          this.startPolling();
    }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // stop poll or use exponential backoff polling
    })
```

However, HTTP long polling is mediocre nowadays with concepts such as server push, one way to implement them is through [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: No idea why someone gave this answer a thumb down, completely agree. Beside that, he is also right about the need to subscribe for the request to actually trigger.

Comment: @enf0rcer Long Polling is a well recognized technique. It is outdated in times of WebSockets, but still valid for legacy systems and when you can't quickly implement a new session architecture (which is pretty difficult when it comes to scalability). Also it does not matter when you map - before or after the subscribtion.

Comment: @Phil thanks for the feedback, I'll do my research better before I answer next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your PollingService should only focus on the HTTP request, and let any components call it.

```
@Injectable()
export class PollingService {

    url: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private fooService: FooService) {}

    startPolling() {
        this.url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/poll';
        return this.http.get<any>(this.url);
    }
}
```

Your component:

```
export class YourComponent implement OnInit{

constructor(private pollingService : PollingService,
            private fooService : FooService){}

theMethodYouWantToConsumeTheService(){
    this.pollingService.startPolling().subscribe(
        //If success
        (pollData) => {
            console.log('poll data', pollData);
            this.fooService.mySubject.next(pollData);
        },
        //If error
        (error)=>{
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to provide ability call polling service to any component. It should be independent service which will call REST and waits for response, and when response is received, it will update some local data over services and call another request. Components will be just subscribing these data which will be changed changed by polling service, not polling service itself.